# memory_get_usage() & microtime()

Tags: php, memory, microtime

Good day! I have this code:

```
final class bench
{
    protected static $start_time;

    protected static $start_memory;

   public static function start()
   {
        self::$start_time   = microtime(true);
        self::$start_memory = memory_get_usage(true)/1024;
   }

   public static function finish()
   {
       echo PHP_EOL.'+'.round(memory_get_usage(true)/1024 - self::$start_memory, 3).' Kb load';
       echo PHP_EOL.'+'.round(microtime(true) - self::$start_time, 3).' Time.';
   }
}
```

But when I wanna use this little code here:

```
bench::start();

$array = ['f', 'g', 'f', 'd', 'ff'];

foreach($array as $key=>$value)
{
    echo $key.'f'.$value;
}

bench::finish();
```

I am getting bad results. It is saying me +0 Kb load +0 Time.

So I tried to use this example:

```
$start = memory_get_usage()/1024 . "\n";

for ($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++) {
    echo $i;
}

echo '<br/>+'.round(memory_get_usage()/1024 - $start, 3).' Kb load';
```

And then I got normal results. Why so? Probably, there is something better than the code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working. The memory used is a few bytes ; since round the division to 3 digits, 0kb is displayed.

Comment: Sorry, but I can not understand you. What is meaning "0 kb is displayed"? I tried to change 3 to 5, but It didn't help me

Comment: The memory usage is so low, when you divide it by 1024 and then round it  all you can see is 0. Try to display memory usage difference without dividing or rounding anything.

Comment: Thank you so much!